# How to add Favorite object from UIViewController to UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone

I am currently developing a project that has tableview in which I accessed the Employees_Name from database. if i click one row of this tableview it navigate to ViewController, here from that row i able to access the description of Employee. In this view I have barButton by Label Favorite. what i want is, if i click this button the Employee name should add to another tableView as favorite from description View Controller to Favorite tableViewController. please anyone can send me the code to overcome this problem and thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

First, I would add a boolean "favorite" property to the database.

Then, toggle that property to YES or NO based on taps on the Favorite button in the description view controller for the selected employee.

Finally, in the favorites table view, filter the employees by only looking for those with the favorite property set to YES.

Comment: what you told me, I did as it is. but after quitting the app. it is not persistant. To make it persistant, how to update the database?